# Domino check access in linked document

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

Situation:

I have two documents: **doc_parent** (has access fields) and **doc_file**(public doc).
**doc_file** has field "*parent_unid*"( with unid of doc_parent ) and field "*$file*" with attachment "file_name.doc"

User get attachment by link looks like: http://server/base/view/doc_file_unid/$file/file_name.docx.

I it possible to check current user access to **doc_parent**, when he makes this request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it while directly accessing the $file object. You would have to have the access to the file go through an agent via a URL that looks something like this:

```
http://server/base/checkAccessAndRetriveFile?OpenAgent&fileunid=doc_file_unid/&filename=file_name.docx
```

And then you would have to write the agent and check the access fiends in doc_parent.

There is nothing built-in that you can rely on.

On the other hand, you could just have those access fields exist in both doc_parent and doc_file, and then none of this would be necessary.

Comment: I thought that, thank you for answer.

Comment: It actually could also be done through something called a DSAPI plugin, which is written in the Notes C API and built into a custom DLL that you would have to deploy on the server. It's been nearly 20 years since I worked with that technology, but I'm sure it's still around. The idea is that the DSAPI plugin would be called whenever a web request comes in. Most of the time it ignores the request and just lets it pass through, but when it recognizes that the request is going for doc_file, it does the extra work to retrieve doc_parent and check the access fields before allowing the request.